# Regular expression to amend Sysprep.inf file

Tags: regex, autoit

I currently have a requirement to parse a sysprep.inf file and insert a value input by the end user. 
I'm coding this utility using AutoIT and my regular expression is slightly out. 
The line I need amending is as follows:

`ComputerName=%DeviceName%`

DeviceName is variable injected by LANDesk. If the device has previously been in the LANDesk database the name is injected into the file. If not the variable name remains. The device name must go after the `=`

Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
$FileContents = StringRegExpReplace($FileContents,'ComputerName=[a-z]','ComputerName='& $deviceNameInput)
```

Thanks for any guidance anyone can offer.

Comment: Are you saying you only want to do the replacement if the string matches `ComputerName=%DeviceName%` or are you saying you want to do the replacement no matter what the rvalue of `ComputerName=` is?

Comment: @HairOfTheDog yes I would like the replacement to occur regardless of what follows ComputerName=

Comment: If my answer below helped you please accept it and up-vote it. If my answer didn't help you please let me know how it falls short and I will update it.

Comment: @HairOfTheDog I will test your answer this evening and get back to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoit has a great way of dealing with ini files - IniWrite

```
IniWrite("SysPrep.ini", "write_section_here", "ComputerName", $deviceNameInput)
```

creates or updates SysPrep.ini with:

```
[write_section_here]
ComputerName=localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with AutoIT or BASIC... but it looks like you need to be using something like this:

```
$FileContents = StringRegExpReplace($FileContents,'.*ComputerName=(\%[a-zA-Z]*\%).*', $deviceNameInput)
```

OR

```
$FileContents = StringRegExpReplace($FileContents,'ComputerName=\%[a-zA-Z]*\%', 'ComputerName='&$deviceNameInput)
```

this will only replace a device name that's a-z or A-Z. Not numerical or containing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Writing regular expressions can be tough because there are so many dialects of regular expressions. Assuming you are using a regex library that supports a Perl-like dialect you might want to try this for your regex:

`^\s*ComputerName\s*=\s*(?:%DeviceName%|[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`

Basically this regex will match an lines either the litteral string `ComputerName=%DeviceName%` or `ComputerName=<some actual device name that only contains the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, and ->`. This regex is also a bit lenient in that it will match a line that contains whitespace at the beginning of the line as well as before and/or after the equals sign. The image below explains the components of this regex in greater detail.

p.s. that image was generated by [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), an excellent regular expression IDE.

[image]